# Concatenate Unknown Multiple Text Files While Inserting a Divider After the Contents of Each File Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For this problem in shell script, I need to accept an unknown multiple number of texts files and concatenate them. But I need to put a divider such as (-----) after the contents of each file. There also needs to be an exit code for the script where if it succeeds then it prints out the correct output. But if it fails it needs to print out this help message, "Usage..." (It's long and the help message itself isn't that important.)

I already figured out how to accept multiple number of text files to concatenate them but the problem is the divider really.

I also figured out how to show the help message using cat but the problem is that I don't know what conditions I need to put for the if and else statement because the conditions itself isn't working as intended.
For example, if it can find txt files and print the output it works as intended, however if there is no txt file it doesn't print the help message.

I am pretty sure it has to be some kind of loop statement for the divider to work but the problem is I have no idea how to do it. Not even sure of the conditions.

```
# Don't know what condition to put for the if here
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
 # Don't know what condition to put for the for loop here
 for j in "$?" 
 do 
   cat *.txt
   echo "-----"
 done
exit 0
else
 cat <<< "Usage..." >&2
exit 1
fi
```

Let's say we have 2 text files.
one.txt has:

```
Hello
```

two.txt has:

```
Happy
```

Then if the code runs as intended the output should be:

```
Hello
-----
Happy
-----
```

Comment: You can read both file simultaneously in while loop and then print each after other.

Answer (score 1):

Something amongst those lines ?

```
#!/bin/bash

for param in $@; do
  if [[ -f $param ]]; then 
    cat $param 
    echo "-----" 
  else
    echo "wrong parameter passed! usage:..." 
    exit 1
  fi
done

exit 0
```

To explain quickly :

```
for param in $@; do
```

Iterate over every parameter passed to the script

```
[[ -f $param ]]
```

This checks whether the parameter is an existing file

Comment: Yeah around those lines. It compiles but it doesn't print. I think it's missing something to print. Let me know if you figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path instead of just file name? IE.: cat /location/of/file.txt

Comment: Not trying to do a file name. It needs to accept all text files that are in that specific directory.

Comment: @user20304030 - _It compiles …_ - How do you compile a shell script?